# Autocomplete an input type=text AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, database, html

What is the name of the technique where a form is autocompleted using the database without reloading the page?

For example, the technique used by Google or Facebook to guess the friends you're look for after typing few letters.

Comment: "autocomplete" or "typeahead". See http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ or http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/

Comment: Oooo, I like those! I'm wondering, though, if the OP needs a real AJAX search using PHP and MySQLi... the two you have put up have values stored in a jQuery array

Comment: it's a good idea but if i've more than 9999999999  item in the database. i'll get issues of time @BigChris

Comment: Thanks @Matt for the correction and your answer.
i'll check your links

Comment: But your question specifically talks about a database... and can you seriously see your database having 9 billion entries? You'll also be surprised of the performance of a MySQL database - obviously sites like Facebook and Google have insane data centers and servers dotted around the world with super-fast connections, but they have the budget.

Comment: And even then, Facebook, it only queries with limits such as friends of friends etc, which is tiny compared to the actual number of users it has IN TOTAL.

Comment: @BigChris (and user3077766): jQuery UI Autocomplete [supports remote data sources](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote). I haven't used typeahead before, but [it seems it might as well](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#remote).

Comment: Ayyy, looks quite good! I've learnt something new today :D Thanks @Matt

Answer (score 1):

When you have a small list, you can also use html datalist.
It isn't the technique used by Google or Facebook, but a nice alternative!

- [W3Schools Datalist](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp)
- [W3C Documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-datalist-element)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist)

Comment: Could you give an official source than w3schools like w3c?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your ajax callback you need to call the response function; passing the array that contains items to display.

```
jQuery("input.suggest-user").autocomplete({
source: function (request, response) {
    jQuery.get("usernames.action", {
        query: request.term
    }, function (data) {
        // assuming data is a JavaScript array such as
        // ["one@abc.de", "onf@abc.de","ong@abc.de"]
        // and not a string
        response(data);
    });
},
minLength: 3
});
```